# Converting string to email-attachment on android

Tags: android, email, attachment

So I have som data that I have converted to a string. While I have found how to attach something from the SD-card to a mail, I cant figure out how to directly convert my string to a mail-attachment without involving the SD-card. In case it holds significance, I have read some data from a database, converted it to csv-format, and now wants to attach it as a csv-file.

Cheers,

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your correctly, but basically you want to attach a cvs file (which is stored where?) to an email?

Comment: I create the csv-file programmatically. It is created only to be mailed, and can then be disposed of. It feels unnecessary to demand that the user has an SD-card for this.

Comment: I have the same problem on Android 4.x. If you found a solution, I am interested.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i try to send a file without saving it in filesystem.
I tried to add a data uri al stream extra like this:

```
String fileContent = "File Content";

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, 
  Uri.parse("data://text/plain;base64,"+ 
    _utils.Strings.base64_encode(fileContent)));
```

I used my own class to create the base64 content, but i think it will also work with:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

It was a success in that case, that saw the atached "file" in my e-mail client.

But there are 2 problems:
 1. I don`t know how to define a name for this file
 2. an error occours when i try to send the file and I get a mail without attachment at the other end.

UPDATE 2015-05-13:
The mail app displays following error for my attachent:

```
E/Gmail(11511): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: data://text/plain;base64,
```

I think that means my phone is yust missing an content provider which can handle data uris.
So I think we have to create ContentProvider (see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html)

And implement a

```
openOutputStream(android.net.Uri)
```

to return the content of the data uri.

Answer (score -1):

create a temporary file using the file API's and then you can go ahead and put it as extra in the email intent like this

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(csvFile));
```

Comment: I did try to create a file and put it in the application directory, but gmail refused to accept a file from that directory. Most likely to prevent some kind of security issue where important app-files could be stolen as email-attachment.

Comment: I save file using createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix) and it works wonderfully fine for me

Comment: Hi @the100rabh, can you give an example on how you made this work? Thank you!

Comment: The topic is "String to email attachment", and the question says "without involving the SD-card". So tempfiles are not the way whats needed.